# I am getting runtime error, I am not able to get two char value a & b

Tags: c

If I give input 'hello' for variable `s` and `a` for variable i cant able to give input

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    char s[100],a,b;
    //i am not able to get this value,please help me how to get three variables s,a,b at runtime
    scanf("%c",s);
    scanf("%c",a);
    scanf("%c",b);
    int n=strlen(s),count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(s[i]==a && s[i+1]== b)
            count++;
    }
    printf("%d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%c` needs an address. You pass it a char. Use: `scanf("%c",&a);`. Note that `s` is OK as an array decays to a pointer to its first member.

Comment: To read a string, use: `scanf("%s",s);`

Comment: Could you please tell us what exactly this program is supposed to do?

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer) about `%c` format and newlines.

Comment: input format: string value for variable s , second line to get charecter for variable 'a' and third line to get another charecter for  variable 'b'  but i cannot able to give input in proper manner

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to use `scanf("%c",&a)` [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).
Then read the three variables using just one `scanf`.
Try this program it will resolve your problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char s[100], a, b;
    //i am not able to get this value,please help me how to get three variables s,a,b at runtime
    scanf("%s %c %c", s, &a, &b);
    int n = strlen(s), count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++){
        if(s[i] == a && s[i+1] == b)
            count++;
    }
    printf("%d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When scanning character, use white space before character modifier, and pass char as pointer, not as value. For scanning entire string, use modified `%s`. In this case, you don't need to write `&s` as `s` itself is already contain memory address of array. If you still want to use `&` infront, then use `&s[0]` because `&s[0] == s`.

```
char s[100], a, b;
scanf("%s", s);
scanf(" %c", &a);
scanf(" %c", &b);
```